# Prevent VS 2017's debugger from opening every Typescript file used

Tags: debugger, visual-studio-2017

On a fresh installation of Visual Studio 2017, I am running into a minor annoyance while debugging an aspnet project in chrome. When the debug app starts up, It opens every typescript file (that is being included in the current document object model of the app) in Visual studio.

I would like to unclutter my workspace since my screen is very small. How can I prevent these files from opening automatically?

Comment: Does this still happen? There have been a lot of VS2017 bug fixes since then.